# How to verify params[:][:] value by "assigns" in rspec controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, parameters

Following is my controller code:

```
 def create
        params[:order][:user_id]=current_user.id
        params[:order][:company_id]=current_company.id
        :
        : 
 end
```

In my rspec controller test i want to test create method so in that i have to test for

```
assigns(params[:order][:user_id]).should eq(user)
assigns(params[:order][:company_id]).should eq(compnay)
```

user and company i set in let and stub as current_user,current_compnay so i get the value for current_user.id andcurrent_company.id . My issue is how can i verify params variable in which we provide value in controller.

currently above rspec lines not working. can anyone help me to resolve above issue?

Answer (score 0):

should be:

```
controller.params[:order][:user_id].should eq(user.id)
controller.params[:order][:company_id].should eq(company.id)
```